# Limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^{\frac{5}{3}}\cdot[{(x+\sin{\frac{1}{x}})}^{\frac{1}{3}} -x^{\frac{1}{3}}]}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^{\frac{5}{3}}\cdot\left[{\left(x+\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} -x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $\frac1x=h$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{x^{\frac{5}{3}}\cdot\left[{\left(x+\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} -x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h\sin h)^{\frac13}-1}{h^{\left(\frac53+\frac13\right)}}$$

**Method** $1:$

Using Binomial Expansion ([1](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem#General_Binomial_Theorem), [2](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem)) , $(1+x)^n=1+nx+O(x^2)$ and  as $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=1\implies \sin h $ is $O(h)$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h\sin h)^{\frac13}-1}{h^{\left(\frac53+\frac13\right)}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac13h\sin h+O(h^4)}{h^2}=\frac13\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h$$

**Method** $2:$

As $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2-ab+b^2),$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h\sin h)^{\frac13}-1}{h^{\left(\frac53+\frac13\right)}}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h\sin h)-1}{h^2\{(1+h\sin h)^{\frac23}+(1+h\sin h)^{\frac13}+1\}}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h\cdot\frac1{\lim_{h\to0}\{(1+h\sin h)^{\frac23}+(1+h\sin h)^{\frac13}+1\}}\text{ as }h\ne0 \text{ as }h\to0$$

$$=1\cdot\frac1{\{(1+0)^{\frac23}+(1+0)^{\frac13}+1\}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Elementary hint:

Multiply the function by $$1=\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+\sin(1/x))^2}+\sqrt[3]{x(x+\sin(1/x))}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{(x+\sin(1/x))^2}+\sqrt[3]{x(x+\sin(1/x))}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$$ and use the basic well known fact that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ to get $1/3$.

Comment: $+1 \ddot\smile$ Hello, dear friend!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello dear one. I hope you're feeling better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$x+\sin \frac1x = x\left(1+\frac1x \sin \frac1x\right)$$ and use
$$\sin \frac1x=\frac1x - \frac{1}{3!x^3} + \frac{1}{5!x^5}+ \ldots, \quad x \to \infty.$$

Comment: Can you please do a full solution with Taylor expansion please?

Comment: We need only the first term of the Taylor expansion: $\sin \frac1x=\frac1x+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$. See lab bhattacharjee's "Method 1" for details.

Answer (score 1):

$$Limit=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^2[(1+\frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x})^\frac{1}{3}-1]=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^2\frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{3x}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: How did you do the before - last step? From the third root.

Comment: $\sin\frac{1}{x}\leq1$ while $x\rightarrow\infty$, thus an infinitesimal. Then by using $(1+x)^\alpha-1\sim\alpha x$

Comment: How do I know that I can omit the other terms?

Comment: Of course, you can expand to higher terms and you will have a sense when you get familiar with this